# In Delphi, how to deserialize a JSON document from std::map in C++?

Tags: json

I have some json string come from c++, std::multimap<double,std::string>,this json string such as:

"{"name":"mark","data":[1,2,3,4],"some":"11.1":"Hello","22.2":",","44.4":"World"}}".

When I try to use mormot to deserialize this JSON string, it is failure, I don't have a appropriate struct to receive it!

So, in Delphi, How can I deserialize this json string :"{"1.1":"Hello","2.2":"world"}" to TDictionary<double,string>?

Comment: `"1"` is not a number/an Integer, it's text. `1` would be.

Comment: It is my wrong! Thank you, In fact the json-string is such as:"{"name":"mark","data":[1,2,3,4,5],"some":{"11.1":"Hello","22.2":",","44.4":"World"}}", it comes from a complex struct , include std::multimap, but I can not receive it and save to a record in delphi.

Comment: Wanting a record of unknown structure/object doesn't make sense, as you still would not know how to access (and why) single properties of it. At some point the program must know that it must expect keys like `"name"` and `"11.1"` and why it would be interested in the values they hold. Furthermore you're expected to edit your question instead of adding contradicting comments - take the [tour].

Comment: Because lots of strings come from c++ std::multimap<double,std::string>,and now i must translate it to Tdictionary<double,string>and use it,if I let you confuse, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there are many ways of doing this. We use the [SuperObject](https://github.com/pult/SuperObject.Delphi) library.

Include SuperObject in your uses clause and then you can parse your object and access the values like this...

```
var
  obj: ISuperObject;
  val: string;
begin
  obj := SO('{"foo": true}');
  { .S is just one of many helper functions. }
  val := obj.AsObject.S['foo']
end;
```

If you don't know the key:value pairs in advance you can iterate over the object like this.

```
var
  item: TSuperAvlEntry;
begin
  for item in obj.AsObject do
  begin
    item.Name;
    item.Value;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes. I can parse any json string,But if this string will translate to a record, record must be define, And It's impossible to know the key string and the value in advance,Maybe can RegisterCustomSerializer for it?

Comment: @ckok That library also allows you to iterate over the object as an array by index, you don't have to know the keys in advance. I added another sample from the github docs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion！I didn't know much about SuperObject before, Under your suggestion, I used the deserialization method of the custom class, created TDictionary in the deserialization function by traversing the names and obtaining the value through the name, and finally solved it, thanks again! !

Answer (score 0):

this is my test code,it can work now.thanks!

`TDstring = TDictionary<double, string>;`

```
class procedure c_method.CustomReadClass(var Context: TJsonParserContext; Instance: TObject);
var doc: TDocVariantData;
begin
  if Context.ParseObject then
  begin
    if not assigned(Instance) then Instance := TDstring.Create;

    TDstring(Instance).Clear;

    var s : u8string := add_bracket(Context.json); //'{ ' + Context.json + ' }'

    doc.InitJson(s);
    var nameList := doc.Names;

    for var i :integer := 0 to High(nameList) do
    begin
      TDstring(Instance).TryAdd(To_string(nameList[i]).ToDouble, doc.s[nameList[i]]);
    end;

    Context.ParseEndOfObject;
    Context.Valid := true;
  end;

end;

initialization
TRttiJson.RegisterCustomSerializerClass(TDstring, c_method.CustomReadClass, nil);

finalization
TRttiJson.UnRegisterCustomSerializerClass(TDstring);
```